# MySql changing date format

Tags: mysql

I got a lot of customers data who did put their birthday in wrong format.

0000.00.00

00-0000-00

0000-00-00

0000/00/00

etc..

mainly 6-7 variations

How can I fix it so that all have year-month-day format, using some query? The field type is `varchar(255)`.

Comment: Hard to do 100% correctly since for example 1/2/3 can be Jan 2 2003, Feb 1 2003, Feb 3 2001, ... If you manage to clean them up, you should _really_ consider using a `DATE` datatype instead of a `VARCHAR`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the DATE_FORMAT() function. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp